# notepad++ regular find and replace

Tags: regex, notepad++

i am trying to find bow from lines then  replace **specialty**  with **specialty (aspeed 700)**

with notepad ++ regular expression

```
(item (name 767) (Index 567) (Image "wea098") (Action 10 2) (class weapon bow) (code 1 2 2 2) (country 2) (level 56) (wear 1) (limit archer 56) (range 176) (buy 0) (sell 1) (endurance 30) (maxprotect 150) (specialty    (Str 1) (Dex 4) (Attack 172 232) (hp 150) (mp 50) (hit 72)))

(item (name 770) (Index 570) (Image "wea101") (Action 10 2) (class weapon wand) (code 1 2 1 3) (country 2) (level 56) (wear 1) (limit mage 56) (range 18) (buy 0) (sell 1) (endurance 30) (maxprotect 150) (specialty   (aspeed 1000) (Int 5) (Attack 150 160) (Magic 220 300) (mp 250) (hit 64)))
```

i tried

```
Find What : .*class\s*weapon\s*bow.*specialty[^.]
Replace With \1 (aspeed 700)
```

results is :

```
(aspeed 700)   (Str 1) (Dex 4) (Attack 172 232) (hp 150) (mp 50) (hit 72)))
```

the results that i want should be :

```
(item (name 767) (Index 567) (Image "wea098") (Action 10 2) (class weapon bow) (code 1 2 2 2) (country 2) (level 56) (wear 1) (limit archer 56) (range 176) (buy 0) (sell 1) (endurance 30) (maxprotect 150) (specialty (aspeed 700)   (Str 1) (Dex 4) (Attack 172 232) (hp 150) (mp 50) (hit 72)))
```

Thx

Comment: I think you probably need parens around your entire regex to make it a group so you can use it with \1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `bow` will always come before `specialty` then use this:

```
Find what:     (.*bow.*)(specialty)
Replace with:  $1specialty (aspeed 700)
```

If `bow` ever comes after `specialty` it would probably be easiest to do this with two regexes, the one above and this one:

```
Find what:     (specialty)(.*bow.*)
Replace with:  specialty (aspeed 700)$2
```

If you are hard core then you can probably combine these two regexes, I just can think of a way to do it right now :)

P.S. Older versions of Notepad++ have issues with regexes.  Get the [most recent version](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download) (6.3 at the time of this writing) to make sure you don't have issues.